# How to customize and turn off sonar rule in SonarQube extension for VS code

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, visual-studio-code, sonarqube-web

I am using [SonarQube extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=silverbulleters.sonarqube-inject) for VS code which enable me to write non-bugy and quality code. but some of the sonar rules not applicable for my code like:- we are using file naming convention "*-component" postfix with each file.

**severity: 'Warning'
message: 'Rename this file to "es6 class name".'**
here SonarQube extension want me to keep file name and class name same.

So i want to turn off these all warning and error those not applicable to my code.

I am looking for a solution/hack to turn off SonarQube rules in vs code extension.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Connected Mode](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html#Connected), which will allow you to run locally with the rule set applied at the server. (Presumably you've already edited the Quality Profile on the server to exclude these rules, right?)

Comment: Absolutely right [G. Ann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662707/g-ann-sonarsource-team), I need something like [Connected Mode](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html#Connected) but It's only for Visual Studio, and i am a web developer using light weight  [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) editor.